# sql agent job notification email without configuring database mail

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

Is there any way to send sql agent job notification email without configuring Database Mail?

Currently I am using Database Mail but due to security concern, i need to disable Database Mail feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email from t-sql code using sp_send_dbmail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql